# Connecting to ssas using powershell script

Tags: powershell, ssas, powershell-core

I tried the code using powershell and its working but in powershell core I get the following error.

**

Error Message:
Exception calling "Connect" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."

Error in Line:
$server.connect($ServerName)

**

Answer (score 0):

Not quite enough code to determine the exact problem, but it sounds like you're importing and using the native SSAS library. Does your code have something like this?

```
$ass = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Microsoft.AnalysisServices”)
$server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$server.connect($connection)
```

There are native PowerShell modules you can use here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/powershell/analysis-services-powershell-reference?view=asallproducts-allversions

Comment: GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v4.0.30319     C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\System.Security.Principal.dll

Error Message:
Exception calling "Connect" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."

Error in Line:
$server.connect($ServerName)